# RecyclerView doesn't respect height=wrap_content?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-recyclerview

I have a chat screen which contains two views : a recycler view for displaying previous chat and a custom view which encapsulates an edit text, a send button, and another recycler view to let user select other things to send like photos, etc. This custom view is called "Panel".

So, my chat activity has the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <chat.example.app.widget.Panel
        style="@style/PanelStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:id="@+id/panel" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/previous_chat"
        android:layout_above="@id/panel"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my "Panel" view has the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/staging_area_root"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <!-- Chat box and send -->
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- THIS GUY IS PROBLEMATIC -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/card_set"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/staging_area_root"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that the recycler view from `Panel` gobbles up entire screen space. So all I see is Mr. problematic recycler view from Panel class.

Both these recycler views have `LinearLayoutManager`s assigned to them. **No adapters yet.**

I have the latest support library in my `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
```

and going over the latest android developers blog post:

> This release brings an exciting new feature to the LayoutManager API:
>   auto-measurement! This allows a RecyclerView to size itself based on
>   the size of its contents. This means that previously unavailable
>   scenarios, such as using WRAP_CONTENT for a dimension of the
>   RecyclerView, are now possible. You’ll find all built in
>   LayoutManagers now support auto-measurement.

Have I missed something ?

**Update 1:**

I added an adapter to Mr. problematic recycler view with 0 items in it. Still no solution.

**Update2:**
Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Instead of using `android:layout_gravity` on your `Panel` use `android:layout_alignParentBottom` and `android:layout_centerHorizontal`. I copied-pasted your layouts, removing the `Panel` xml and replacing it with its layout xml and everything looks alright on the preview in Android Studio.

Comment: @AlexTownsend no luck. As an update, I **am** using `alignParentBottom`. Haven't updated code here, yet. Perhaps it has something to do with the way my custom view is created ?

Comment: could you post a screenshot of the Preview in Android Studio or a screenshot of the screen from a device/emulator?

Comment: @AlexTownsend which screenshot would u like? with the properties you asked me to change? :)

Comment: @AlexTownsend Done. Blue recyclerview is from `Panel`.

Comment: alright, I was getting the full screen blue until I added adapters with actual items to both `RecyclerViews`. I was able to get [this](http://i.imgur.com/4fYBpTT.png) as a result.

Comment: @AlexTownsend So looks like adapters are imperative. What happens when the blue recyclerview has 0 items in its adapter ? :)

Comment: When blue has 0 items, it will appear as the full screen like you are seeing. My guess is that the auto-measurement that the `LinearLayoutManager` does needs to be based off the size of all the children in the `RecyclerView`. Because there are no children in the `RecyclerView`, the auto-measurement does not take place, and the `RecyclerView` will take up the full height.

Comment: @AlexTownsend Interesting edge case this. What if my recycler is populated with items from the server and the server returns no items. Looks like adding an "empty" view is a must now :-/

Comment: It certainly looks like that will need to be the case.. or just hide the `RecyclerView`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Code snippet taken from the 23.2 `RecyclerView` `onMeasure()` call:

```
if (mLayout.mAutoMeasure) {
        final int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
        final int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);
        final boolean skipMeasure = widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY
                && heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;
        mLayout.onMeasure(mRecycler, mState, widthSpec, heightSpec);
        if (skipMeasure || mAdapter == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (mState.mLayoutStep == State.STEP_START) {
            dispatchLayoutStep1();
        }
        // set dimensions in 2nd step. Pre-layout should happen with old dimensions for
        // consistency
        mLayout.setMeasureSpecs(widthSpec, heightSpec);
        mState.mIsMeasuring = true;
        dispatchLayoutStep2();

        // now we can get the width and height from the children.
        mLayout.setMeasuredDimensionFromChildren(widthSpec, heightSpec);

        // if RecyclerView has non-exact width and height and if there is at least one child
        // which also has non-exact width & height, we have to re-measure.
        if (mLayout.shouldMeasureTwice()) {
            mLayout.setMeasureSpecs(
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getMeasuredWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getMeasuredHeight(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
            mState.mIsMeasuring = true;
            dispatchLayoutStep2();
            // now we can get the width and height from the children.
            mLayout.setMeasuredDimensionFromChildren(widthSpec, heightSpec);
        }
    }
```

The `mLayout.setMeasuredDimensionFromChildren()` call will do the auto-measuring based off of the size of the children of the `RecyclerView`. Meaning, a valid `RecyclerView.Adapter` with 1 or more children is needed for the auto-measurement to trigger.

Comment: Can't spam the +1 button. Thanks a ton. :)