# 23.2.0 RecyclerView "WRAP_CONTENT" won't support views created programmatically

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Here is how I did it with the 23.2.0 RecyclerView.

```
TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
textView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
textView.setText("GO SYNC CONTACTS!!!!!");
textView.setTextSize(30);
```

Then I add this view to the first position of my RecyclerView in adapter.

Turns out there's a big empty space of this TextView.
Other views which are inflated by XML works just fine.

Comment: Have you checked this question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35726839/recyclerview-doesnt-respect-height-wrap-content

Comment: Please [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475178/how-do-i-make-wrap-content-work-on-a-recyclerview/35623177#35623177) answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think u should set params fro the parent of the TextView not for the ActualView(TextView),Try this once and let me know

```
ParentOfYoyrTextView.LayoutParams paramsExample = new ParentOfYoyrTextView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, since the the TextView is a direct child of RecyclerView, so I'm assuming it is a ViewGroup kind of LayoutParams? I also tried RecyclerView.LayoutParams, still not working. But I also tried inflate a XML file outside the adapter(in fragment), and pass the inflated view to the adapter, and still not working. I think that's something wrong this the Parent View. I'll keep look into this problem. Thanks!

Comment: set black color to your text view once and check pls.